# SSRS Report document map link goes to page before (another subreport) because the subreport it refers to contains a page break before

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-2012, reportingservices-2005

I'm using SSRS Report Builder to modify a report that I am currently very happy with. It is composed of several sub-reports, each inside their own rectangle on the main report. I am trying to add a Document Map so that our users can more easily navigate the digital version of the report.

Because the report is primarily reviewed in PDF/Physical form, I also use a rectangle *inside* each subreport which has the "page break before" option enabled, so that each subreport will have its own page.

I tried setting the Document Map label for the subreport, and have also tried setting the label for the rectangle that each subreport sits inside. In both cases, when I run the report, the Document Map link takes me to the page preceding the subreport. I believe this is due to the subreport actually starting on that page, but the only content on that page is the page break.

I have also tried putting each subreport inside its own page-break rectangle rather than putting the page-break rectangle inside the subreport, with the same result.

Is there a way that I can, either through code or configuration, load the correct page when a Document Map link is clicked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by taking the page break out of the rectangle *inside* the subreport and putting a page break after the rectangle *containing* the subreport. Now the actual top of the subreport is on the first page that contains data. The Document Map is loading the correct page now.